# Why do I get garbage values only in G++ for Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, garbage-collection, g++, turbo-c++

I have this issue while using the g++ compiler particularly. I get seemingly random garbage values (Blue Highlight), with the desired output (Green Highlight), although I want to get rid of these garbage values. When I run the same program on the TurboC++ compiler, it runs perfectly (Orange Highlight) without any garbage values. Can anybody explain to me why this happens and how to get rid of it ? I'm considerably new to Linux so,a detailed explanation would be very appreciated.

a) The G++ compiler garbage values
[image: The G++ compiler garbage values]

b) The TurboC++ compiler perfect execution.
[image: The TurboC++ compiler perfect execution]

Comment: There's probably a bug in your code. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] *in the question itself* and *as text* so we can diagnose said bug.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I have no actual bug in the code. It compiles perfectly. I even get the desired output. I just can't get rid of the garbage values.

Comment: The differences between Turbo C++ and g++ are massive, about 20 years, and the C++ language being standardized. One should almost expect them to work differently.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And yes you have a bug in your code. Just because it compiles doesn't mean it works. And just because it ***seems*** to work doesn't mean it actually does. The "garbage values" is a sure sign there is a bug in your code.

Comment: @PranavAbraham *"I even get the desired output. I just can't get rid of the garbage values."* is somewhat self-contradicting.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for the Feedback

Comment: Please do not use images where copy&pasted block quotes would do perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing array where it has not been initialized.

Instead of `i=c`

You should `i=c-1`

Comment: Mark as answer if it has answered your question